# $f(16x)=16f(x) $ and $ f$ is continuous

Tags: functions, continuity, functional-equations

$f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(16x)=16f(x)$ for every real $x$.

Should it be $f(x)=ax$? How can I prove that?

Comment: Hint: Continuous functions are uniquely determined by their values at the rationals.

Comment: Similar problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350618/fx2-2fx-and-fx-continuous/350644#350644

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly $f(0)=0$. Also, if we have a solution defined for negative $x$ and for positive $x$, we can simply combine them.

Let $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be any continuous function with period $1$ - that is, $h(x+1)=h(x)$ for all $x$.
Define $$f(x)=xh(\log_{16} x)$$ for $x>0$.

This gives an arbitrary $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R$ which satisfies $f(16x)=16f(x)$ and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ (the latter because $h$ is bounded.)

It is not hard to prove this gives all such functions.

This is essentially the same answer as several above, but with a cleaner formula that lets us see the relationship between the "obvious" examples $f(x)=ax$ and this general example,  $f(x)=xh(\log_{16} x)$.

The general solution is, given $g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous with period $1$ (that is, $g(x+1)=g(x)$ and $h(x+1)=h(x)$ for all $x$) then:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}xg(\log_{16} x)&\text{if }x>0\\
xh(\log_{16} (-x))&\text{if }x<0\\
0&\text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$

is an example, and this covers all examples.

Given an $f$ which satisfies the above rule, define $$g(t) = \frac{f(16^t)}{16^t}$$ for $t\in\mathbb R$. We can easily show that $g(1+t)=g(t)$ that $g$ is continuous, an then, letting $t=\log_{16} x$ for $x>0$ we see that $f(x) = xg(\log_{16} x)$.

Similarly, let $h(t)=\frac{f(-16^t)}{16^{t}}$.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not true. For example, $f(x)=|x|$. However, it will be true if $f(kx)=kf(x)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Or can we find all $f$s

Comment: If $f(kx)=kx$ then $f(x)=x$. Not sure what you mean by that statement.

Comment: If $kf(x)=kx$ then $f(x)=x$ too.

Comment: It seems any combination of two linear functions will work: $f(x) = \begin{cases} ax & x \geq 0 \\ bx & x \leq 0. \end{cases}$

Answer (score 5):

Let $g,h\colon[1,16]\to\mathbb R$ be two continuous functions with $g(16)=16g(1)$ and $h(16)=16h(1)$, but otherwise arbitrary.
Define
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}16^kg(u)&\text{if }x>0\text{ with }k:=\lfloor\log_{16}x\rfloor, u:=\frac x{16^k},\\16^kh(u)&\text{if }x<0\text{ with }k:=\lfloor\log_{16}|x|\rfloor, u:=\frac {|x|}{16^k},\\0&\text{if }x=0.\\
\end{cases}$$
Then $f\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous(!) and $f(16x)=16f(x)$ for all $x$.
This gives us a *lot* of examples and in fact all examples (for given $f$, functions $g=f|_{[1,16]}$ and $h=(-f)|_{[1,16]}$ produce $f$ again).

Comment: Don't you mean $h(x)=f(-x)$ restricted to $[1,16]$?

Comment: It is much easier to start with $g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with periods $1$, $g(x+1)=g(x)$ and $h(x+1)=h(x)$ and define the functions $f(x)$ as $xg(\log_{16} x)$ when $x>0$ and $xh(\log_{16} x)$ when $x<0$.

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of non-linear solutions for the functional equation, you can even demand them to be smooth everywhere (except at the origin):

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
x \left(A_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \sin(2\pi k \log_{16}|x| + \alpha_k)\right)& x > 0\\
0 & x = 0\\
x \left(B_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k \sin(2\pi k \log_{16}|x|+ \beta_k)\right)&  x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
where $A_k, B_k, \alpha_k, \beta_k$ are arbitrary constants.

Notice $f(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(16^{-n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}16^{-n}f(1) = 0$. 
If one futher demand $f$ differentiable at $0$, then for all $x \ne 0$, we have:

$$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(16^{-n}x)}{16^{-n}x} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = f'(0) \implies f(x) = f'(0)x $$

i.e. The only solutions which are differentiable at $x = 0$ are the linear ones.

Comment: What if we add a statement like $f$ is surjective?

Comment: @user706071. Even bijectivity won't help. Consider the non-linear solution $f(x) = x \left( 1 + \frac13 \sin(2\pi \log_{16}(|x|)\right)$. Notice the factor $\sin(2\pi\log_{16}(|x|))$ is bounded by $\pm 1$, it is easy to see $f(x) \to \pm \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. This means $f(x)$ is surjective. If you compute $f'(x)$ at $x \ne 0$ and plot it out, you will find $f'(x) > 0$. This implies $f$ is injective.