# How do I find a function $f$ such that $f(x^2)=2f(x)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Does there exist a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x^2)=2f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$? How do you solve this? I understand that this is nothing like a normal equation, because you can't solve for $x$, or $f(x)$, because of that $f(x^2)

Comment: What about $f(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Are there any nontrivial solutions?

Comment: Is there any restriction on the domain of $x$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$f(x^2) = 2f(x)$ and $f(x)$ continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350618/fx2-2fx-and-fx-continuous) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x%5E2)%20%3D%202f(x)%24&p=1)

Comment: $f(x) = \max( 0, \log x^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)=\frac12 f(x^2)$ is even, we just need to check $x>0$. Clearly $f(1)=0$. If $x\in(0,\,1)$, $$0=f(0)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(x^{2^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2^nf(x))\implies f(x)=0.$$But we may obtain nonzero $f(x)$ if $x>1$. A comment by @achillehui notes that $f(x)=\max(0,\,\log x^2)$ works. We can generalize this a little, e.g. we may multiply by a constant, or (I think) multiply $f$ for $x\ge2$ by $1+\{\log_2(\log_2 x^2)\}$ where $\{y\}$ is the fractional part of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

For $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ we have a cool function that works, the $\log$ function. This works with any base, is nontrivial, and satisfies your things. To extend this to negatives, set $f(-x)=f(x)$. I'm sorry about $0$, but let's just keep it out of the domain.

Comment: That's discontinuous at $x=0$.